# Get date From ISOdate in MongoDB JSON

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have 3 rows available in MongoDB and I have converted the resultData to Json.
    Now JsonData contains all three records in single Array and one of its field "InsertTime" has value ISODate("2014-05-05T15:26:23.645Z");
    And I want this ISODate in simple Date object for all JSON output.

```
var resultData = coll.FindAs<RecentSearch>(qrySelectedParam).OrderBy(e => e.RefId).ToList<RecentSearch>();

var JsonData = resultData.ToJson();

Thank You in Advance.
```

Comment: What's a "simple date" object for all JSON output mean? Could you add an example? The ISO date format is a relatively common way of expressing a date in a JSON document.

Comment: This is my value in MongoDB, "InsertTime" : ISODate("2014-04-25T17:20:56.288Z"). And I want In JSON Object as - Date(4/25/2014 5:20:56 PM)

Comment: You'd need to write a custom serializer. A date doesn't have a formal standard representation in JSON: http://json.org/